# sort a JavaScript/JSON object with Underscore

Tags: underscore.js

I wanted to sort the JSON file below by specifically the trouser's stock level of each product, but I'm not sure how to write the code using the function _.sortBy, I made a start but not sure how I specifically target the stock level of the trousers. It should be the lowest stock level first. Any ideas? Thanks!

SCRIPT:

```
var sortedArray = _.sortBy(templateData, function(stocklevel) {
    return stocklevel[0].looks
});
```

JSON:

```
var templateData = {
    listTitle: "Shop by Look",
    looks: [
        {
            id: "Sportswear Look 1",
            products: [
                {
                    name: "Shirt",
                    pid: "50",
                    stock_level: 1,
                    image: "img/look1.jpg"
                },
                {
                    name: "Trousers",
                    pid: "40",
                    stock_level: 7,
                    image: ""
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            id: "Sportswear Look 2",
            products: [
                {
                    name: "Shirt",
                    pid: "50",
                    stock_level:5,
                    image: "img/look2.jpg"
                },
                {
                    name: "Trousers",
                    pid: "40",
                    stock_level: 16,
                    image: ""
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to sort the `templateData.looks` array, not the `templateData` wrapper object.

The iterator function given to `sortBy` will be called with each one of the sorted objects, i.e. the "shop" objects in here. When you want to return the stock level of the trousers, you need to get that object. If you don't know where it is, you will need to search it in the products array at first, Underscore's [`findWhere`](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) will help you with that.

```
var sortedArray = _.sortBy(templateData.looks, function(shop) {
    return _.findWhere(shop.products, {name:"Trousers"}).stock_level;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I get this error: TypeError: _.findWhere(...) is undefined
[Parar en este error]  

return _.findWhere(shop.products, {name:"Trousers"}).stock_level;

Comment: Update your underscore version to at least 1.4.4

Comment: actually it returns this: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: Ah, I though at first it was a `method not found error`, but it could indeed be that `_.findWhere(…)` returns `undefined` - when nothing is found. What should happen if one of the shops does not sell trousers?

Comment: in the example I am using the stocklevels are always more than 0, if one of the products has 0 then it shouldn't be shown.

Comment: Then you would need to add a `_.filter(templateData.looks, function(shop) { var t = _.findWhere(shop.products, {name:"Trousers"}); return t && t.stock_level > 0;})`

Comment: thanks, but I still get an undefined array like so [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: That doesn't look like `undefined`, that looks like a stringification of an array of objects. What else did you expect?

Comment: but how can I make it return actual data?

Comment: Don't stringify it? It *is* data. If you want a JSON representation back, use `JSON.stringify()` on it.